# Фильтрация данных на React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Есть некий массив с данными, которые приходят с сервера, надо выполнить сортировку по состоянию options.

```
const blocks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        workNumber: 1,
        variant: 1,
        status: 1,
        questions: [''],
        likes: 0,
        bought: 1,
        method: ['excel', 'word']
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        workNumber: 2,
        variant: 1,
        status: 2,
        questions: [],
        likes: 2,
        bought: 2,
        method: []
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        workNumber: 3,
        variant: 2,
        status: 3,
        questions: [],
        likes: 2,
        bought: 2,
        method: []
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        workNumber: 2,
        variant: 2,
        status: 3,
        questions: [],
        likes: 2,
        bought: 2,
        method: []
    }
]

const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    variant: 0,
    workNumber: 0,
    status: 0
})
```

Каким образом можно сделать сортировку сразу по нескольким параметрам, а потом ещё и сброс всех фильтров, или по одному.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю что Вы хотите сделать, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
const filterBlocks = (options, blocks) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(options);
  return blocks.filter((block) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const field = keys[i];
      if (options[field] !== block[field]) return false;
    }
    return true;
  });
};

filterBlocks(options, blocks)
```

> а потом ещё и сброс всех фильтров, или по одному.

Вы можете меняя `options` или `blocks` вызывать эту функцию.

```
useEffect(() => {
  filterBlocks(options, blocks); // and set this data to another useState
}, [options, blocks]);
```

UPD: Не совсем удачно назвал аргументы, думаю вы разберетесь

Comment: Спасибо огромное